# Open Hardware: Why does it Exist if you can License Hardware Under Standard Open Source License?

Tags: licensing, hardware

I was looking into publishing some hardware I designed. I began to look into the world of Open Hardware License(s) and discovered the closest to the GNU GPL TAPR and CERN (strong copyleft). And figured out that you can just use a GPL and others like MIT. Why does OHW exist and how/why is it different from OSS?